# how to use nsdictionary to split strings and swap values

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm new to ios, trying to do something like this

```
self.dataArray = [dictionary valueForKey:@"LIST"];

{
  "List": [
    {
      "FULLNAME": "FirstName, LastName",
      "ID": "281"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to swap the value which is in 'FULLNAME', that is I want it to be LastName, FirstName

I tried various methods but it would not work. Can someone tell me how to accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know how to do the dictionary manipulation, here's one way to swap the elements in the string:

```
NSString* name = @"Firstname, Lastname";
// Remove the space after comma (not necessary if you know the name will always
// have a space after comma, then just split on ', '.
NSString* normalizedName = [name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@", " withString:@","];
// Split the string on ','.
NSArray* nameParts = [normalizedName componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
// Reverse the array
NSArray* reverseNameParts = [[nameParts reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
// Join the array with ', '
NSString* revname = [reverseNameParts componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
NSLog(@"Reversed name parts: %@", revname);
```

Comment: how do I put it back into dictionary?

Comment: To answer that, I would need to know more about the dictionary. In general, make sure the dictionary is mutable and then use `[dict setObject:revname forKey:@"FULLNAME"]` (after extracting it from the array and outer dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be objectForKey instead of valueForKey, if your dictionary contains arrays.

```
self.dataArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"LIST"];
    for(NSString *fullname in self.dataArray){
        if([fullname isEqualToString:@"FULLNAME"]){
            NSArray *name = [fullname componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
            NSMutableString* reverseName = [NSMutableString string];
            for (int i=[name count]-1; i>=0;i--){
                [reverseName appendFormat:@", ", [name objectAtIndex:i]];
                //reverse name should be what you are looking for..or something close
            }
        }
    }
```

hope this helps